# How to show the duration time of several mp4 files

Tags: powershell, mp4

I want to extract the duration time of several mp4 files with PowerShell. I found a script that makes what I want, but with this scripts the duration shown is HH:mm:ss, and I want the exact duration time with more precision than seconds, like miliseconds or maybe HH:mm:ss:SSS.

Someone could help me? There is a way to do that?
The script I found is the following:

```
Function Get-VideoDetails {
    param ($targetDirectory)
    $LengthColumn = 27
    $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $targetDirectory -Include *.mp4 -Recurse -Force | ForEach {
        if ($_.Extension -eq ".mp4"){
            $objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
            $objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($_.Name)
            $Duration = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $LengthColumn)
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $_.Name
                Duration = $Duration
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Supply your video directory

```
Get-VideoDetails "C:\VIDS"
```

Comment: In my understanding, `GetDetailsOf` does only give you the same informations that the exlporer gives. Thisway it's natural that it only shows down to the second. This doesn't mean there isn't another way to get the milliseconds. Since the duration is calcualted in 100 ns units, you can probaly grep it somehow (ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-media-duration).

Comment: I guess you would need to call on other software like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/nl/MediaInfo/Download/Windows) to get that information. There is a module on [GitHub](https://github.com/gpduck/PoshMediaInfo) for that.

Comment: I didn't know mediainfo, I liked it, thanks... I exported it to csv, then open with excel but it only shown this columns: name, format, video format, audio format and text format, not the duration. But in the software I can see it if I scrolldown through every file. It's gonna be a lot of work to copy only this information of every file, but I can't figure out other way to do this :(

Answer (score 2):

Using the MediaInfo command line (CLI) build you can try something like this:

```
$VideoDuration = [math]::Round(((C:\MediaInfoCLI\mediainfo '--Output=Video;%Duration%' $File.FullName) / 1000), 3)     # MediaInfo reported Video duration in decimal seconds

$AudioDuration = [math]::Round(((C:\MediaInfoCLI\mediainfo '--Output=Audio;%Duration%' $File.FullName) / 1000), 3)     # MediaInfo reported Audio duration in decimal seconds
```

Comment: In case it is preferred: if you replace "%Duration%" by "%Duration/String3%, you'll get the duration in HH:MM:SS.mmm format (note: the HH:mm:ss:SSS format as requested is usually used for frame number in the last part, it should not be used for milliseconds).